# Mootools - how to refer local 'this' and class 'this' in an Event?

Tags: javascript, mootools

There are 10 *li* elements and 5 of those have *a* element inside. And I'd like to add an event on the *li* elements using Mootools.

A class has few variables and method including the event for the *li* elements and my problem comes from here. please see the event for *li* below,

```
li.addEvents({
    mouseover: function(e){
        console.log(this.id + ' / ' + this.classVar);
    }.bind(this)
});
```

In the event I need to refer *li* itself and a class variable because each *li* has unique *id* and the *classVar* has also information. But problem is if I use *bind(this)* to the event, *this.id* won't work or if not using it, *this.classVar' won't work.

If I use *e.target.id* instead of *this.id*, it returns correct id IF ONLY the *li* doesn't have *a* element. Otherwise *e.target* refers the *a* element.

Can anyone help me on this please? Many thanks in advance

Comment: in jQuery this is done with [`e.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) unfortunately MooTools has [`wontfix`](https://mootools.lighthouseapp.com/projects/2706/tickets/803-event-should-include-currenttarget-property) on that... this made me cry a little. You must use a closure and `self` hack because there is nothing [here](http://mootools.net/docs/core/Types/DOMEvent) either

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way is to use the `self` or `me` workaround, like so...

```
function myClass()
{
    var self = this;
    this.classVar = 'foo';

    // some other code

    li.addEvents({
        mouseover: function(e){
            console.log(this.id + ' / ' + self.classVar);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: +1 - also this is the cheapest. when using `.bind(this)` you need to rely on the event object and get the current one via `event.target`. though in the OP example you can use the `li` variable also.

Comment: Wow it works! Thanks very much both. Very valueable tips for me.